cannot import name 'AzureOpenAI' from 'openai'
I'm getting this error when I'm trying to make a package and consume it in a flask app.
I tried everything from switching to a more stable openai version to rebuilding my application. nothing seems to work. Please help!!!

Firstly, please check current version of OpenAI by running the below command:

pip freeze | grep openai

Please uninstall the existing OpenAi version and install OpenAi version 0.28.1 package and test again ?

pip install openai==0.28.1

Sharing a similar thread from GitHub, if that helps.
